# Comando para excluir todas as pastas menos as três mais recentes

Tags: linux, shell

No servidor da minha aplicação, gostaria de manter um histórico de releases da mesma. Entretanto, não quero manter todas, até porque raramente teremos que fazer rollback para releases muito antigos.

Assim sendo, gostaria de saber qual o comando para excluir todos os releases, menos os três mais recentes.

Obrigado!

Comment: Linux, correto?

Comment: @Sanção isso mesmo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o comando

```
ls -t diretorio/sub_diretorio | tail -n +4 | xargs rm -r
```

- `ls -t` lista os arquivos ordenados por data, mais recentes primeiros
- `tail -n +4` exibe a partir do 4º elemento da lista, ignorando os 3 primeiros
- `xargs` passa os itens da lista para o comando `rm -r` que remove os arquivos/pastas de forma recursiva